# How to change timestamp in javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, timestamp, timezone, node-red

I have that thing written in JS that put a timestamp on a sensor data to store it in a database. My problem is : The timestamp is early 2 hours.

So I would like to know how to add two hours in the script so that it write the good timestamp in the database.

Thanks !

```
var sqliteTimeStamp = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000); //converting to seconds instead of milliseconds epoch
var theDevice = "growtent";
var theSensor = "t01";
var d = new Date();
var epoch = d.getTime();

var theSQL = "INSERT INTO sensor_data (device,sensor,value,epoch) VALUES "
theSQL = theSQL + "('" + theDevice + "', '" + theSensor + "', '" + msg.payload + "', " + epoch +");";
msg.topic = theSQL;

// Update the status with current timestamp
var now = new Date();
var yyyy = now.getFullYear();
var mm = now.getMonth() < 9 ? "0" + (now.getMonth() + 1) : (now.getMonth() + 1); // getMonth() is zero-based
var dd = now.getDay() < 10 ? "0" + now.getDate() : now.getDate();
var hh = (now.getHours() +2) < 10 ? "0" + now.getHours(): now.getHours();
var mmm = now.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + now.getMinutes() : now.getMinutes();
var ss = now.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + now.getSeconds() : now.getSeconds();
node.status({ fill: "blue", shape: "ring", text: "Last update: " + dd + "." + mm + "." + yyyy + " " + hh + ":" + mmm + ":" + ss });

return msg;
```

Comment: use UTC? It's unclear what *'The timestamp is early 2 hours.'* means. A moment in time can't be early

Comment: Hey ! 
Sorry it wasn't clear. I get 9:00 when it is 11:00. Can you help me ?

Comment: Sounds like a timezone issue. Just use the UTC date methods.

Comment: I am a total noob, can you help me a bit more please ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you live now but I live in Korea so 
I use this flow for get my real-time data.
Try to exchange Asia/Seoul or Korea to your country.

```
[
{
    "id": "fd1274d6d8fe341f",
    "type": "tab",
    "label": "플로우 2",
    "disabled": false,
    "info": "",
    "env": []
},
{
    "id": "6c89c2c523692d4d",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "fd1274d6d8fe341f",
    "name": "",
    "props": [
        {
            "p": "payload"
        },
        {
            "p": "topic",
            "vt": "str"
        }
    ],
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "onceDelay": 0.1,
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "",
    "payloadType": "date",
    "x": 160,
    "y": 80,
    "wires": [
        [
            "63e4c965fe9d5977"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "01ece3685f12fb3d",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "fd1274d6d8fe341f",
    "name": "debug 28",
    "active": true,
    "tosidebar": true,
    "console": false,
    "tostatus": false,
    "complete": "false",
    "statusVal": "",
    "statusType": "auto",
    "x": 500,
    "y": 80,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "63e4c965fe9d5977",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "fd1274d6d8fe341f",
    "name": "function 17",
    "func": "var time = new Date().toLocaleString('ko-KR', \n{ timeZone: 'Asia/Seoul' });\n\nmsg.payload=time;\nreturn msg;",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "initialize": "",
    "finalize": "",
    "libs": [],
    "x": 330,
    "y": 80,
    "wires": [
        [
            "01ece3685f12fb3d"
        ]
    ]
}
]
```